# Couldn't catch(construct) the right router

Tags: node.js, fastify

I read https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Routes.md

But my router doesn't seems to catch  the right url with params

Url : `/app/name?id=666&method=3&_=1553342444710`

I tried:

```
fastify.get('/app/:id-:method:*', (request, reply) => {
fastify.get('/app/*', (request, reply) => {
fastify.get('/app/:id-:method:-:_', (request, reply) => {
```

Comment: `fastify.get('/app/*'`
Seems works after all

Comment: `:param` define path parameter, you cant read the query params in the url declaration. so `'/app/*'` will reply for all the route like `app/foo` not only `app/name`. So what is the wanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fastify.get('/app/name', {
  schema: {
    querystring: {
      id: { type: 'integer' },
      name: { type: 'string' },
      _: { type: 'integer' },
    }
  },
},
(request, reply) => {
  ...
```